# Where is my Android phone's mount point, so I can rsync it?

Tags: command-line, android, automount, rsync, mountpoint

I would like to rsync my music with my Android phone (Galaxy Nexus), I'm trying to work out the mount path to use from the shell. The `mount` command doesn't show up on the phone. In Nautilus the location of a music file is shown as:

```
gphoto2://[usb:001,009]/Music/foo.mp3
```

How would I mount this location from the shell?

(I know about Banshee and other music players. I just want to use the easy, reliable, crashless rsync.)

```
% cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS \n \l

% uname -a
Linux guava 3.2.0-35-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 17:42:16 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Did you look in /mnt or /media ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'm on the road and I'll check the solutions when I can :-)

Comment: Did you ever get it sorted out?

Comment: No - it got put into the "too hard backet", though gvfs-mount -l is hand

Comment: I recommend this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/342549/62638.  I can `cd` and use `ls`, etc.  I haven't yet found how to write a new file or `cp` ... _work in progress_

Answer (score 2):

`gphoto` is automounting your Android device. To find out where the actual mountpoint lies, use `gvfs-mount -l`. I believe the actual mountpoints all end up in `~/.gvfs`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 tablet, and it seems to act the same as yours.  It does not get mounted automatically very well at all, and not in any usual way.  I have sometimes gotten it to mount correctly, although often none of the folder contents are visible.

So, I started looking into it just today, and discovered a method that works very well, using this site: http://blog.itsbilal.com/index.php/2012/12/connect-an-android-4-0-phonetablet-to-ubuntu-the-reliable-way/

He mounts it in a subdirectory of your home directory; for my setup, it creates two folders, "Card" and "Tablet".

The storage is not in any of the usual places, but that doesn't really matter.  I haven't actually figured out how to make it automatically mount using fstab, but I did create two shortcuts to mount and unmount on demand.  If you want Unity quicklists, there was an article [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html) that might help, although I didn't use this one.

PS... I believe that the phone needs to be unlocked in order to mount successfully.

Comment: That link seems to be broken.  Perhaps you can post the key elements?

Comment: I don't remember anything about this now, but I did a google search on "connect an android 4.0 phone or tablet to ubuntu the reliable way", and found hits, such as: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjImcXM4rvSAhUBUWMKHamvAZUQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpetescan321.tumblr.com%2Fpost%2F55039283616%2Fconnect-an-android-40-phonetablet-to-ubuntu&usg=AFQjCNHj3Xsan5TZgEzRWkkcrQiCKMCAig&sig2=oEAYpaij2OExgsOgz2UGew, and other hits.

Answer (score 1):

I rsync to my android like this (bash script):

```
if [ -n "`lsusb | grep -i Samsung`" ]
then
    phone=`mktemp --directory`
    go-mtpfs $phone &
    sleep 3s
    # Setting -T /tmp even though this is a security risk (/tmp race).
    # Without that rsync fails on renaming .foo to foo for some reason.
    opts="--archive --delete --update --progress -T /tmp"
    rsync $opts ~/from/my/stuff $phone/Card/stuff
    fusermount -u $phone
fi
```