# How to rsync to android

Tags: android, rsync

How can I connect to my android device to rsync music (or other stuff)?

Comment: I recommend editing this to explain exactly what action produced that error message. (For example, if it's the output of a command, you could include the full command.)

Comment: maybe interesting: [Syncopoli](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.amoradi.syncopoli/)

Comment: @DJCrashdummy if you write your comment as answer, I will up-vote it.

Comment: @guettli i wrote this only as comment, because [Syncopoli](https://gitlab.com/fengshaun/syncopoli) is just a rsync-client (for now).

Comment: Whatever is the method to run `rsync`, i recommend to create a hotspot on the machine and connect the Android device to the hotspot. This can drastically increase the synchronization speed.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55359419/can-rsync-be-used-to-transfer-files-from-android-client-to-linux-server-programm

Answer (score 45, accepted):

## Using sshelper

I found this solution:

- Install [sshelper](http://arachnoid.com/android/SSHelper/) on the device (no rooted device needed, available from google play market)
- In my WLAN the device is called "android". But you can use the IP, if you can't give the device a hostname.

Edit local ssh-config, to alter the default port for host "android"

```
.ssh/config
host android
    Port 2222
```

- Start sshelper on device.
- Connect android device to you WLAN.

> rsync -rvlc Music android:SDCardLink/

**Update**
<del>I prefere `-rvlc` to `-a` since you get a lot of warnings since setting permissions and time-stamps does not work. The option `-c` makes the second sync much faster.</del>

I prefere `-rvl --size-only` to `-a` since you get a lot of warnings since setting permissions and time-stamps does not work. The option `--size-only` makes the second sync much faster.

Unfortunately it needs some time for music apps to see the new files. Restarting the device helps.

Comment: An alternate way to use rsync with SSHelper without having to modify .ssh/config: `rsync -avz -e 'ssh -p 2222' Music android:SDCardLink/` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4630407/399105)

Comment: @guettli  what for -c checksum option to syncing music files ? this can slow down significantly

Comment: @EdiD why should `-c` slow down things significantly? Please explain it.

Comment: @guettli from rsync man :  -c, --checksum.
 Without this option, rsync uses a "quick check" that (by default) checks if each  file’s  size and  time of last modification match between the sender and receiver.  This option changes this to compare a 128-bit checksum for each file that has a matching size.  Generating the checksum means that both sides will expend a lot of disk I/O reading all the data in the files in the transfer,  so  this can slow things down significantly.

Comment: @EdiD ok, but AFAIK syncing the mtimes does not work. I guess that rsync without `-c` does stumble over this.

Comment: @guettli I guess that  `--size-only` would be the fastest solution. However it's not so save as `-c`

Comment: I used USB tethering and got much faster transfers. The following command worked for me after I ran SSHelp and it showing IP `192.168.1.5` which might be different everytime: `rsync -avzhP --inplace --info=progress2 -e 'ssh -p 2222' 192.168.1.5:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/  /home/username/path/to/pics/`

Comment: I don't know if it is something new in newest sshelper, but now `SDCardLink` is simply `SDCard`. So You need to use: `rsync -rvl -e 'ssh -p 2222' ./WhatsApp/Media/ 192.168.2.102:SDCard/WhatsApp/Media/`

Comment: This no longer works due to a recent Android OS update breaking SSHelper.

Comment: @JonathanNeufeld can you please provide a link to the particular change?

Comment: @guettli I don't have a link, I just emailed the author directly.  He says he is trying to get more feedback on the issue in order to get to the root cause.  I dug up that old thread and found this was the error message it was giving me at the time "CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "-bash": library "libTcpOptimizer.so" not found".  He suggested that it may work if you reinstall it, but I did not have as much luck.  It might work on a brand new phone that has never installed it prior to Android 9.

Comment: This still works for me on Android 7.1.1 and is an awesome replacement for `adb pull` which fails for all kinds of reasons

Comment: @JonathanNeufeld I'm successfully using rsync in both directions over wifi between SSHelper 13.0 on Android 10 (Pixel 3a) and Debian stable (aka Buster).

Answer (score 79):

## Actually using rsync over MTP/usb

It's easier than everyone is saying, first notice that when GVFS mounts the MTP mount it'll be available under. You can force this by opening the phone up in a graphical file-browser (thunar/nautilus/etc)

```
/run/user/$UID/gvfs
```

go in there. Assuming you have one mtp device, this should work:

```
$ cd /run/user/$UID/gvfs/mtp*
```

Find where you want to transfer the files too, and then rsync them to it

```
$ cd SanDisk\ SD\ card/Movies/

$ pwd # prints "/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A003%2C096%5D/SanDisk SD card/Movies"

$ rsync --verbose --progress --omit-dir-times --no-perms --recursive --inplace ~/Videos/ ./
```

### Rsync options

- `--inplace`: I **highly** suggest using `--inplace` without which mtp may want to copy the file a new, and then rename it to the old one. That may result in copying the file to the SD card twice: once for the mtp transfer to the SD card, and another time because the MTP driver may not support (mv), it may (cp/rm) under the hood to be safe.
- read man rsync for a description of `--verbose`, `--progress`, `--recursive` but they're pretty self-documenting.
- `--omit-dir-times` `--no-perms` are required because mtp doesn't support that.

Comment: I add the following options `--omit-dir-times --no-perms --ignore-existing`.  Rsync fails to set directory timestamps over MTP.    I'm pretty sure that "no permissions" is the default, but I like to specify it.   Ignoring existing files allows it to pick up where it left off.

Comment: Why `--ignore-existing`? That's just losing redundancy. You could always `--size-only` which reduces the sync to the directory listing and not checksums. I'm going to add the `--omit-dir-times` and `--no-perms` because that sounds useful, and I seem to recall getting an error at the end about that.

Comment: Rsync has problems setting time stamps over MTP properly for me, so without `--ignore-existing` it tries to sync all the files.    I like your `--size-only` suggestion.   I'll try that instead next time.

Comment: I also use put the trailing slash on the destination so I don't have to use a star on the source: `~/Videos/ ./`

Comment: I also had to add '--delete-after' to get it to delete files I'd already removed from the music folder on the computer. So the full command is:
rsync --verbose --progress --omit-dir-times --no-perms --recursive --inplace --ignore-existing --delete-after /home/user/MUSIC/ .

Comment: NOTE: This didn't worked until i used `sudo`

Comment: I'm still getting "rsync: open /run/user/1000/gvfs/... failed: Operation not supported (95)" without sudo  or "rsync: ERROR: cannot stat destination /run/user/1000/gvfs/... Permission denied (13)" with sudo. Any tips?

Comment: This way of doing defeats rsync: your are transferring the whole data from the android device to your computer!

Comment: this works well with `jmtpfs` too - don't mount with sudo.

Comment: For me this only creates folders but does not transfer files.

Comment: I voted this up b4 waiting "copy" end. It cant copy! As torsten said  gives error only in the end! Now the site dont let me remove the vote... android 6.0.1 here, no root, that may be the problem.

Comment: @JohanBoulé I tested this method and it definitely completed faster than actually copying files, so some data transfer is saved

Comment: I still ended with a bunch of errors like rsync open failed: Operation not supported. All the files appear to be transferred though...

Comment: We are in 2023 and it's still a complete foobar. Considering Android is Linux based it is a enourmous travesty towards the decades of Linux development Google scams of off. Windows works seamlessly but Linux is a try and might get lucky or use decades debugging faults. IMO they should have had the courtesy to prioritize the millions of users that have made their system usable in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

None of the above did quite what I was looking for. Specifically part of the OP's question: how do I `rsync` my music to my Android phone? Well, I took parts of the suggestions from these answers and wrote my own Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting rsync with Android."

src_dir="/home/joshua/Music"
dst_dir="/run/user/$UID/gvfs/mtp:host=OnePlus_HD1925_SERIAL/Internal shared storage"
rsync --progress \
      --human-readable \
      --omit-dir-times \
      --no-perms \
      --recursive \
      --inplace \
      --size-only \
      --exclude='*.jpg' \
      --exclude='*.JPG' \
      --exclude='*.jpeg' \
      --exclude='*.JPEG' \
      --exclude='*.png' \
      --exclude='*.bmp' \
      --exclude='*.txt' \
      --exclude='*.pdf' \
      --delete \
      "$src_dir" "$dst_dir"

echo "rsync operation is done. Enjoy the music :)"
```

I just dropped this in `~/.local/bin` where I've got other scripts (your system's default `PATH` should actually already have this directory). You just have to make sure that File Transfer is on and that the storage is actually mounted before you run it. Nothing bad will happen if you don't: `rsync` will just yell at you.

This script:

- Takes into account that Androids can't retain ext4 style metadata on files
- really is faster than the other options in my experience, using `size-only`
- Excludes album covers and scans from flooding your phone's file system :)
- Really syncs! It deletes stuff when you delete from the source, like fixing song metadata and replacing it with the correct file instead of keeping two copies.

---

Also, if you choose this answer specifically because you like the `--exclude` tags, you might also need a way to do clean-up on your phone if it already synced a whole bunch of unwanted images:

```
# Remove all *.jpg and *.JPG from the current directory, recursively.
find . -iname *.jpg -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 4):

[rsync backup for Android](http://android.kowalczuk.eu/rsync4android/) can be configured to sync in reverse, that is from a Linux host to Android device.

And with the help from [LlamaLab Automate](https://llamalab.com/automate/) one can configure the Android device to rsync automatically on specific conditions, e.g.:

1. at 5 am,
2. when the phone is connected to a specific Wi-Fi, and
3. when it is charging.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a solution to rsync FROM android to NAS for images backup.

Grsync, graphical version of rsync, worked just [fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIp25.png).

Fortunately, it also can rsync TO android. The only problem -- it can not preserve time stamps so all transferred files will have time stamps of the moment they were rsynced.

```
    sudo apt install android-file-transfer
    sudo apt-get install grsync
```

It seems that -a key I was using in the command line to rsync from android does not work with mtp: when I check "preserve permissions" and "preserve owner" and "preserve group" in grsync no file is transferred. 
Default grsync settings "preserve time", "Verbose" and "Show transfer progress" just works.

While rsyncing to android -t key should be ommited: files will be transferred but rsync will give errors on not preserving time stamps.

Grsync output for command line FROM android:

```
    rsync -r -t -v --progress -s /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp\:host\=%5Busb%3A001%2C013%5D/Micro\ SD/test /home/FREENAS/
```

Grsync output for command line TO android:

```
   rsync -r -v --progress -s /home/FREENAS/test /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C013%5D/Micro\ SD/
```

where run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C013%5D my android phone mount point.

Comment: Why did you install android-file-transfer?

Answer (score 3):

## Using Termux

[Termux](https://termux.com/) brings a whole lot of Linux command line utilities to Android, including `rsync` and `openssh`.

You can set up an SSH server on your Android device, then use `rsync` over SSH, provided both your PC and your Android device are on the same WLAN connection.

The Termux Wiki clearly explains the steps required to [set up SSH](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Remote_Access#SSH) and [use `rsync`](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Remote_Access#Rsync).

To sum up:

1. Set up Termux

   - [Install Termux](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.termux/)
   - Grant Termux filesystem access (`Storage` permission) from Android settings
   - Open Termux
   - Set up a password

     ```
     $ passwd
     New password: 
     Retype new password: 
     New password was successfully set.
     ```
   - Update the list of packages

     ```
     $ apt update
     ```
   - Optionally, upgrade the existing packages as well (this solved a compatibility issue in my case)

     ```
     $ apt upgrade
     ```
2. Set up `openssh`

   - Install openssh

     ```
     $ apt install openssh
     ```
   - Start the ssh daemon

     ```
     $ sshd
     ```

     It listens on port `8022` by default.
3. Install `rsync`

   ```
   $ apt install rsync
   ```

To get started, all you need is:

- Your username on Termux

  ```
  $ whoami
  u0_a223
  ```
- The IP address of the Android device

  ```
  $ ip -4 a | grep wlan0 | tail -1
      inet 192.168.1.101/16 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global wlan0
  ```

  which, in this case, is `192.168.1.101`.

Now, you can do pretty much anything with `rsync`. For example, if you wish to copy the `~/Music` directory from your PC to the Android device's `/sdcard`, you could do something like:

```
$ rsync -e 'ssh -p 8022' -aP ~/Music u0_a223@192.168.1.101:/sdcard
```

When prompted for a password, enter the one you set earlier.

Comment: Thank you. Works for me on android 13 (Galaxy-Note10-5G).

Comment: Great solution for those that are used to using terminals, you can also setup crond to backup at a set frequency. If the target is also an android, make sure to setup crond at target and run `termux-media-scan -r $source_folder`to notify apps of new files, for example triggering Google Photos to sync to cloud.

Answer (score 2):

I know that the OP wanted to use rsync, but if the idea is to sync directories, I strongly recommend  using `syncthing`. Many, many, benefits:

- it will run continuously, no need to fire it from time to time;
- it will sync many different folders, to many different devices, at the same time;
- you can use `syncthing` as part of a backup solution for your cellphone, in two steps: (1) you sync all important data from your cellphone to an external host (2) you setup a backup solution on that host.

I personally sync all important data from any device I own to at least another device, possibly two, located in physically different places; at least one of these devices has raid disks; I  then add `snapper` to one device, so that old versions of all files are kept; or you can use a feature of `syncthing` to accomplish the same results.

One last note of warning. If you run out of space on one device, that device will stop syncthing, but you will not get any error from it, so you should check from time to time. If you use `snapper` it is quite easy to fill up disks, *caveat emptor*.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `rsync` over MTP, but in my case, the speed was really slow. If you want to try it, here is a suggestion.
My solution is based on the following source:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=261904

I use Kubuntu, so, there is no MTP folder in the `/run/user/1000/gvfs/` folder.
I downloaded the following package:

https://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/simple-mtpfs-0.2-3.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm

There is the binary file that worked on Kubuntu 20.04. You can find it in the `bin` folder and unpack it into a folder.
Unfortunately, on Plasma, it may not mount the device until we kill a specific process. Then you can use the `fuser` command.

First, you need to find your device with the `lsusb` command:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 2717:ff48 Xiaomi Inc. Mi/Redmi series (MTP + ADB)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3fd Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD WebCam (Asus N-series)
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04fc:05d8 Sunplus Technology Co., Ltd Wireless keyboard/mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:08a0 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Gaming mouse [Philips SPK9304]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here we need to copy the `2717:ff48` MAC address of the Xiaomi device.
Run the following lines and replace `2717:ff48` with your device's MAC address:

```
DATA=`lsusb | grep '2717:ff48'`
echo $DATA
# Reading the bus number:
BUS=`echo ${DATA:4:3}`
# Reading the device number:
DEV=`echo ${DATA:15:3}`
# Killing the process which is using the device (if any)
fuser -k /dev/bus/usb/$BUS/$DEV
```

Then you can run the binary file and specify your path for the mounted folder:

```
./simple-mtpfs --device 1 /tmp/xiaomi
```

---

However, as the speed was really slow, I just gave up, used a card reader, and synchronized the files from a local folder to the USB device. Maybe, that was the easiest option.
In my case, this is the best option because the destination folder has some files to be deleted, and to extend the life of an SD card, it is better to not delete or create new files when it is not necessary.

Comment: Killing the process using the device part is useful even when using some other mtp-fs program. I'm using [Android File Transfer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Media_Transfer_Protocol#Android_File_Transfer).  It works great, but sometimes fails to mount the device as KDE/Gnome grabs the device first. The steps you've mentioned here is useful when that happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My Two Cents:

termux only works for integrated storage and a certain directory on external cards in recent devices (mine's running MIUI14) or with rooted devices.

just opening the mtp device in any filemanager to open a terminal from there did not work for me (thunar)

the /run/... directory for gvfs was empty for me despite the device being unlocked and open in the filemanager

I solved this for me by unmounting the mtp device (using the filemanager) and remounting it (using jmtpfs)

Answer (score 1):

The [foldersync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) app can use the SFTP protocol and is very configurable. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to avoid using `rsync` via `mtp` ([media transfer protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol)) and use `adb` - **android debug bridge** if possible.

First install the cli tool, download form [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools#downloads) 
 (in my case I just wanted the cli tool since I'm not an android dev)

Here are the direct steps, in my case I'm on linux:

```sh
$ curl -sSL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip-linux.zip -o platform-tools.linux.zip
$ unzip platform-tools.linux.zip
$ cd platform-tools/
$ ./adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 34.0.5-10900879
Installed as /path/to/adb
Running on Linux 5.18.10-76051810-generic (x86_64)
```

Now connect your phone via USB and activate USB debugging on developer options in android settings

Check your phone is connected

```sh
$ ./adb devices -l
List of devices attached
....REDACTED....         device usb:1-1 product:...REDACTED... model:...REDACTED... device:...REDACTED... transport_id:1
```

Now you can copy local content to the phone via `push` command

Here is the info about the command

```
 push [--sync] [-z ALGORITHM] [-Z] LOCAL... REMOTE
     copy local files/directories to device
     --sync: only push files that are newer on the host than the device
     -n: dry run: push files to device without storing to the filesystem
     -z: enable compression with a specified algorithm (any/none/brotli/lz4/zstd)
     -Z: disable compression
```

Here is an example of the command call

```sh
$ ./adb push /path/from/your/local/ /path/on/your/phone
```

In my case an example of `/path/on/your/phone/.../` looks something like this `/storage/emulated/0/.../`

I got the info from this [reddit comment](https://old.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/8qdus4/usb_connection_is_very_slow_for_file_transfer/e0lil9q) and [this part](https://developer.android.com/tools/adb#copyfiles) from the android docs.