# Access android phone via Ubuntu

Tags: android, remote, remote-access

I would like to connect my android phone to my ubuntu laptop in such a way that any phone calls or notification is shown on my laptop.For example I am working on my laptop and someone calls me on my phone. Incoming call notification pops up on my laptop with option to pick the call. I select the pick the call option and I am connected to the caller. Basically I would like to cast the phone to my ubuntu laptop and have option to control the phone and receive the phone notification on my laptop. Is there such an application available? I am looking for open source solution. Solutions like airdroid, screencast etc does not solve my problem.

Comment: Is "KDE Connect" (on both the laptop and android phone) sufficent? Do you want to use the laptop to talk (with a headset or similar) or do you just want the notfication for the incoming call?

Comment: This is more a question for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep a folder on my computer in sync with a folder on my android device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981804/keep-a-folder-on-my-computer-in-sync-with-a-folder-on-my-android-device)

Comment: tardis, N0rbert thanks for the pointer. I will try out and post the results.