# Rsync to mtp mounted android does not work

Tags: android, rsync, mtp

I tried to sync ogg-audio-files to my android device like this:

```
rsync -av piano /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp\:host\=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/SanDisk/Music/

===> rsync -av piano/ /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C007%5D/SanDisk/Music/
sending incremental file list
rsync: failed to set times on "/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C007%5D/SanDisk/Music/.": Operation not supported (95)
...
foo-bar/one.ogg
...
rsync: mkstemp "/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C007%5D/SanDisk/Music/foo-bar/one.ogg.0gzy9t" failed: Operation not supported (95)
```

But only the directory got created. No file was transfered:

```
===> find /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C007%5D/SanDisk/Music/piano

/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C007%5D/SanDisk/Music/piano/foo-bar
```

How to rsync between my android device and my Ubuntu PC?

I found a work-around: I unplugged the micro-SC card from the android device and inserted it into the sd-card reader of my laptop. But a solution where I don't need to do this would be nice.

Comment: Your "mounted Android" device is probably a VFAT filesystem (see `lsblk -f`) and doesn't support all the times (atime, mtime, ctime see `man ls`) that `rsync` wants to set. `perror 95` tells me `OS error code  95:  Operation not supported`. In a similar problem, I ended up using `cp` instead. Do you really need all the bells and whistles of `rsync`?

Comment: @waltinator I don't need all times (atime, mtime, ...). But I want the copy to be fast if I execute it some days later. I only want to transfer the few changes, not all files again.

Comment: Personally I found SSH/SFTP more convenient. See https://askubuntu.com/a/981883/66509 .

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you need a rooted device for this (I only run rooted LineageOS and am not familiar with other flavours).  In LineageOS, **/system/xbin/rsync** exists by default, else, connect your phone to your PC and start a terminal and execute all of the commands below in the PC's terminal:

```
sudo apt install wget adb
wget -O rsync.bin http://github.com/pts/rsyncbin/raw/master/rsync.rsync4android
adb push rsync.bin /data/local/tmp/rsync
adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/rsync
adb shell cp /data/local/tmp/rsync /sdcard/rsync.bin
adb shell /data/local/tmp/rsync --version
```

- create a configuration file

```
adb shell 'exec >/sdcard/rsyncd.conf && echo gid = 0 && echo uid = 0 && echo address = 127.0.0.1 && echo port = 1873 && echo "[root]" && echo path = / && echo use chroot = false && echo read only = false'
```

- start the rsync daemon on the device

```
# on regular Android
adb shell /data/local/tmp/rsync --daemon --no-detach --config=/sdcard/rsyncd.conf --log-file=/proc/self/fd/2
# on LineageOS
adb shell rsync --daemon --no-detach --config=/sdcard/rsyncd.conf --log-file=/proc/self/fd/2
```

- on a different shell window, start port forwarding

```
adb forward tcp:6010 tcp:1873
```

- happy copying

```
rsync -av --progress --stats --partial rsync://localhost:6010/root/sdcard/DCIM .
```

Comment: I have to remove the lines `gid = 0` and `uid = 0` from the config file (otherwise, I got `setgid failed rsync error`), and I have to be inside the phone with a `adb shell` to start the daemon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a couple of simple solutions, you can try one of these:

1. (My preferred) Install an FTP server on your phone, then use a GUI program (like Filezilla) to transfer the files. I get consistently good transfer rates (6M+) on a 2.4G network.
2. Use a service like AirDroid. It's not great with large files (4G+), but it's great with smaller ones. The free version only allows 200M/month, though.

Answer (score 0):

Today I updated my music on my phone too.
I could run

```
 rsync -vrih --omit-dir-times --no-perms piano /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp\:host\=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/SanDisk/Music/
```

and it worked slowly.

---

There is an other option `--inplace` to make it faster, but i got *Operation not supported (95)* errors too.

Comment: I tried your --options and it made the folders, but all the files said: `failed: Operation not supported (95)`

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` and `cp` did not work for me. They all fail with an error like:

```
cp: cannot create regular file
```

The solution: [gio copy](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/gio.1.html)

Bonus: It's already included on Ubuntu systems.

Example usage:

```
gio copy <src file> <destination mtp folder>
```

This doesn't work recursively for folders, but using:

```
gio copy source_folder/* <dest> will get every file in a folder.
```