# Where is my tablet memory hardware mounted on laptop?

Tags: mount, mtp

I connected my Asus fonepad7 tablet to my laptop via usb. My laptop automatically detects it & opens. But I'm unable to find where the memory card of my tablet mounted on laptop.
Just see below, when I put cursor on the tablet device, it shows "mtp://[usb:002,003]/"
[image: tablet mount point????]

As I'm unable to find the mount point, I can't use command line for accessing the tablet.
Also, commands "mount" & "df" doesn't reflect anything regarding the tablet.

I'm working on Ubuntu 13.04

> EDIT#1

As per one's comment, please find the output of a command below.

```
lsravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2    8:2    0  31.2G  0 part 
├─sda3    8:3    0  36.9G  0 part 
├─sda4    8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5    8:5    0 301.4M  0 part /boot
├─sda6    8:6    0  10.1G  0 part /
├─sda7    8:7    0   2.1G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda8    8:8    0   5.6G  0 part /home
├─sda9    8:9    0   6.9G  0 part 
├─sda10   8:10   0  14.1G  0 part 
└─sda11   8:11   0   3.3G  0 part 
sr0      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: What is the output of `lsblk`? Looks to me like it is mounted using the MTP protocol.

Comment: Seems like this might be a duplicate of this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/342319/where-are-mtp-mounted-devices-located-in-the-filesystem

Comment: @Seth I've posted the output of the `lsblk` command.

Comment: I don't see your phone there, which just goes to prove my point. Your computer isn't mounting it, it is accessing it over the mtp protocol. There is no traditional mount point. Again, see the question I linked.