# How do I mount Nexus 7 to view files from command line

Tags: mount, nexus-7, mtp

I enabled MTP on the Nexus 7 and Nautilus registers it and lets me browse the files, but `ls /media/usbdrive/` shows me nothing. How do I mount it in such a way that I can explore the device's internal storage from the command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are MTP mounted devices located in the filesystem?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/342319/where-are-mtp-mounted-devices-located-in-the-filesystem)

Comment: These devices use the MTP protocol and are handled different to general USB massstorage.

Comment: You are correct, That is the answer I was looking for. Danke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had good experiences with [go-mtpfs](https://github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs), which is a FUSE based file system.

Create a mount point, by default `/media/MyAndroid`:

```
sudo mkdir /media/MyAndroid
sudo chown <user> /media/MyAndroid
```

Once this is done, mount your android device with

```
go-mtpfs /media/MyAndroid
```

To unmount, kill the `go-mtpfs` process followed by

```
fusermount -u /media/MyAndroid
```

There are Ubuntu packages available in a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/unstable)