# Display 'cd' accessible path to mtp device in Nemo

Tags: command-line, android, directory, mtp, nemo

Nemo displays path to mtp device like that:

```
mtp://[usb:001,007]/
```

I want to be able to copy path from Nemo to terminal and `cd` there. Maybe it's possible even with this path while escaping some symbols (tried unsuccessfully)?
Currently I have to do it this way:

```
cd /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C007%5D
```

Answer (score 5):

To be usable as a path you have to [URL-encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the string that you get from Nemo.

To do so the following oneliner should return the command to use to `cd` into your mtp device:

```
echo -n mtp://[usb:001,007] | python -c "import sys,urllib; \
print 'cd /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host='+urllib.quote(sys.stdin.readline().replace('mtp://',''))"
```

it returns:

```
cd /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C007%5D
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not commenting earlier. I've just found your answer not helpful for me (it makes copying easier but not enough for everyday use), but it's also well-researched and I think it's likely helpful for someone else. That's why I've neither accepted/upvoted/downvoted. Also from my point of view my question now looks more like a feature request for Nemo developers, so I'm not even sure if it's legit here (at least it's not a bug report :).