# Unable to successfully mount Samsung phone

Tags: usb, mount, android, mtp

Running 15.10 Wily. Installed using the minimal ISO (network install) and selected Xubuntu core. After installing procinfo and running ls_usb, I can see the device when it's plugged in

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
```

However, the device cannot be found to interact with it and mount the filesystems. I tried following Will's instructions in this thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342319/where-are-mtp-mounted-devices-located-in-the-filesystem/719941#719941), but when I reached step six,

```
sudo mtpfs -o allow_other /media/mtp/phone
```

I get the following

```
    Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 1, dev 11
Attempting to connect device
Error 2: PTP Layer error 02ff: get_handles_recursively(): could not get object handles.
Error 2: Error 02ff: PTP: I/O error
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 2: PTP Layer error 02ff: get_handles_recursively(): could not get object handles.
Error 2: Error 02ff: PTP: I/O error
Listing File Information on Device with name: (NULL)
LIBMTP_Get_Storage() failed:-1
Error 2: PTP Layer error 02ff: Error getting friendlyname.
Error 2: Error 02ff: PTP: I/O error
```

the first time. I tried a second time after dis- and then re-connecting the device again and got

```
Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 1, dev 12
Attempting to connect device
Listing File Information on Device with name: Garm
```

Now, entering t the final command

```
ls -lt /media/mtp/phone/Card
```

returns an error

```
ls: cannot access /media/mtp/Android: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

(I replaced 'phone' with 'Android' in the folder name and commands to better fit my usual naming scheme; it still says 'phone' above because I simply copy->pasted from the other thread)

Please advise.

Further information::
Following another thread which suggested the problem might lie with udev, I attempted [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-enabled-devices-to-work-with-ubuntu/88481#88481), to be greeted with the following error

```
adduser: The group `fuse' does not exist.
```

when attempting to add myself to the group. Should I have such a group?

In order to avoid conflicting 'solutions' (and keep the install as clean as possible), I have since removed

- /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
- mtpfs, mtp-tools (apt-get purge)
- the the /media and /media/mtp folders we created (one was busy and had to be deleted after reboot)

So we should be starting fresh, having undone reversed my earlier attempts.

  -

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
sudo apt-get install jmtpfs
```

Then connect your phone to computer via USB and enable transfer files on mobile.
Your phone should be detected.

Comment: Keep in mind the OP was on 15.10 - which other than being EOL could have been a contributing factor.  Chances are OP might not need the assist anymore.