# How to access Android device in Krusader?

Tags: mtp, krusader

I can access my Android phone in Files (Nautilus), but how do I access it in Krusader?

I can type 'mtp:/' in the Location Bar, but I get this error:

"Error: Protocol not supported by Krusader: mtp:/"

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `mtp://`? You haven't stated what version of Ubuntu you are using, but for me MTP is mounted via `fuse`, so you just navigate to the correct mount point.

Comment: Hi! Using "mtp:", "mtp:/" or "mtp://" makes no difference. I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Where do I find "fuse" and "the correct mount point"?

Answer (score 3):

With the help of [Where are MTP mounted devices located in the filesystem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342319/where-are-mtp-mounted-devices-located-in-the-filesystem/342549) I discovered that my Android phone gets mounted here: /var/run/user/1000/gvfs/ or here: /run/user/1000/gvfs/ - problem solved!

Comment: Not working for me: I do get an MTP entry in that folder, but Krusader can't open it (it's not a folder)