# What is the Android phone MTP mount point in (K)ubuntu 20.04 if not /run/user/1000/gvfs?

Tags: 20.04, mount, kubuntu, android, mtp

There is the question [Where are MTP mounted devices located in the filesystem?](https://askubuntu.com/q/342319/925128) and its answers specify (as I expected and seen in other systems) `/run/user/$USER/gvfs` as the real mount point for my device which otherwise is showed at `mtp:/My Phone/Internal shared storage/`.

(I can access the phone without problems, but I would like to know the mount point because accessing the phone that way this problem [HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/640630/341192) might be solved and because from past experience it allows more options for files in file manager right-click context menu.)

Installing `gvfs-fuse`,the folder `/run/user/1000/gvfs/` is empty.

***Where is the phone mounted then?***

Comment: In a snap perhaps? :) what about `~$USER/.gvfs`? http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/gvfsd-fuse.1.html says `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs` or `$HOME/.gvfs`.

Comment: @Rinzwind - there is no `$HOME/.gvfs`. And before installing `gvfs-fuse` today for the purposes of this and the linked questions there wasn't even a `/run/user/1000/gvfs/` folder on the system - while the phone was accessed as expected at `mtp:/`. Is it possible that the mountpoint here has nothing to do with `gvfs`?

Comment: I think your phone is not mounted at all but is accessed via the [MTP-protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol).

Comment: @mook765 - I have just found and added a Reddit post (I don't know how authoritative) saying that it is not mounted: but being accessed via MTP is not enough for it not to be mounted (on other systems it is MTP-accessed and still mounted at `/run/user/1000/gvfs/ `) , the reason seems to be that "a separate KIO process" is at work. (Whatever these are.)

Comment: @Rinzwind - please see my update, namely the Reddit/kde post saying `Dolphin doesn't mount locations, it accesses them via separate KIO processes. This avoids blocking UI applications.` But can one still *mount* a folder of the Android phone if one pleases?

Comment: **This avoids blocking UI applications** ironically is true. `nautilus` still blocks completely if `mtp` starves, but luckily the rest of the UI continues to work, so you can do `killall -9 nautilus`.  AFAICS KDE was forced to move `mtp` out of the filesystem when Ubuntu implemented the Windows 98 bug called "autostart", which made the X Window Panels bork on starved `mtp` operations.  (AFAICS in 2025 Ubuntu will have implemented all bugs of Windows ME, then they will start to implement all bugs of Windows XP.  **Note that I hate Windows** for all of its bugs being reimplemented into Ubuntu!)

Comment: @Tino - I have never suffered from those bugs myself, I'm much more troubled that by double clicking a +3GB video on the Android device it starts being copied to the computer instead of being played -- and letting me see quickly what's what. Oddly, when the copying to cache takes place, Dolphin displays the transfer as a normal one. But when I copy the file manually Dolphin notifications reports it finished instantly (when it takes place in background). The logical action should anyway be different:  not to copy again the file from source, but to move it from cache.

Comment: @Rinzwind - what about [How to access/mount Android drive in Plasma with other file manager than Dolphin?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1346885/925128).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the Reddit/KDE post [MTP mount location for Android phones under Plasma](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/atjc0u/mtp_mount_location_for_android_phones_under_plasma/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

> **Dolphin doesn't mount locations, it accesses them via separate KIO processes. This avoids blocking UI applications.** I haven't checked if simple-mtpfs uses FUSE to mount MTP, but if it does, it is indeed the solution you are looking for.

> According to https://github.com/phatina/simple-mtpfs:
>
> > SIMPLE-MTPFS (Simple Media Transfer Protocol FileSystem) is a file system for Linux (and other operating systems with a FUSE implementation, such as Mac OS X or FreeBSD) capable of operating on files on MTP devices attached via USB to local machine. On the local computer where the SIMPLE-MTPFS is mounted, the implementation makes use of the FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) kernel module. The practical effect of this is that the end user can seamlessly interact with MTP device files."*

---

I have posted as an answer what initially was posted as an update: the fact that **there is no mountpoint because there is no mount procedure when accessing Android drive in Plasma**. Not all "locations" are accessed in this way, external drives are mounted as expected, but Android locations are accessed in this particular way.

A big consequence is that **other [file managers cannot access](https://askubuntu.com/q/1346885/925128) an Android location as Dolphin does or as they do in other desktop environments**.

Some other odd behavior can be noticed:

- When opening a file from the Android drive (accessed through Dolphin) **the file is *copied* to the local drive (that is to `~/.cache/kioexec/krun/`) before being opened**.
- If - after waiting for the copy to `~./cache` to finish and for the opening of the file - one decides to copy the file manually to the computer, even if that is done on the $HOME partition (that is the same partition as that of the automatic *copy-to-cache*), **instead of just moving that file from `~/.cache/kioexec/krun/` to the paste location, it is *copied for a second time* from the Android drive**.
- While during the automatic copying to cache Dolphin shows normally the transfer progress in notifications, **during manual copy/paste there is no notification progress shown**, as if the transfer was instantaneous. (One would expect *that* to be the case if the paste was on the same partition as the `~/.cache` location, and thus a simple *move* action from there was to be made; but no: the copying is done again from Android, only without notification).

---

The android drive is thus not mounted automatically, but it can be mounted manually, for example as said said [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/a/1346893/925128).