# How to go to the directory of a mobile phone connected to Ubuntu via USB in the terminal?

Tags: usb, android, samsung, mtp

It is connected by mtp it says in file explorer. Displays an address mtp://SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_4d0020574be13109/

Comment: Maybe try this answer? https://askubuntu.com/a/342549/524764

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are MTP mounted devices located in the filesystem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342319/where-are-mtp-mounted-devices-located-in-the-filesystem)